# What two tables are being compared in the SQL Query

Tags: sql, db2

```
private static final String UPDATE_QUERY =
            "MERGE INTO EXAMPLE_TABLE AS table1 USING (" +
                    "VALUES(:value1, :value2, :value3) " +
                    "AS table2 (val1, val2, val3) " +
                    "ON table1.val1 = table2.val1 " +
                    "AND table1.val2 = table2.val2 " +
                    "AND table1.val3 = table2.val3 " +
                    "WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN " +
                    "INSERT (value1, value2, value3, " +
                    ") " +
                    "VALUES (table2.val1, table2.val2, table2.val3)";
```

What I don't understand is since there is only one table specified, in this case "EXAMPLE_TABLE" which is being called table1, how does this query know which table is being referred to as table2 since there is no declaration of the actual table name?

Comment: what dbms is that?

Comment: it is a DB2 dbms

Answer (score 1):

> What I don't understand is since there is only one table specified, . . .

No, there are two. The second one is here.

```
"VALUES(:value1, :value2, :value3) " +
"AS table2
```

That's a table constructor, which you can look up for whatever DBMS you're using. Here's [documentation for SQL Server (T-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: THanks, then I guess what I don't understand is ```"AS table2 (val1, val2, val3) " ``` what is being specified here

Comment: @OpenMeyends: "val1", "val2", and "val3" are the column names in "table2".

Comment: @OpenMeyends: it's essentially the same as a table alias but also providing column aliases for the constant values. See [this example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=1a4d6641fea3595940a4c8e4b632b81a) note the different column names in the two queries